# How to find the equation of other two sides of a rhombus if equation of two sides (intersecting at the origin) and diagonal is given?

Tags: geometry

**Precise Question :-**

Two sides of rhombus, lying in the first quadrant, are given by `3x − 4y = 0` & `12x − 5y = 0`. If the length of the longer diagonal is 12, find the equation of the other two sides of the rhombus.

Answer (score 0):

Let $OABC$ be our  rhombus, $3x-4y=0$ be an equation of $OC$ and $12x-5y=0$ be an equation of $OA$.

Thus, $OB=12$.

We know that $m_{OA}=\frac{12}{5}$ and $m_{OC}=\frac{3}{4}$.

Thus, $$\tan\measuredangle AOC=\frac{\frac{12}{5}-\frac{3}{4}}{1+\frac{12}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{33}{56}.$$

Thus, $$\cos\frac{\measuredangle AOC}{2}=\frac{11}{\sqrt{130}}$$ and
$$OA=\frac{6}{\cos\frac{\measuredangle AOB}{2}}=\frac{6\sqrt{130}}{11}.$$
Now, $A$ and $C$ placed on the circle $$x^2+y^2=\left(\frac{6\sqrt{130}}{11}\right)^2.$$
Thus, for $C$ we obtain:
$$x^2+\left(\frac{3}{4}x\right)^2=\left(\frac{6\sqrt{130}}{11}\right)^2,$$
which gives something very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

From the equations of the two lines we can read their respective direction vectors, $(4,3)$ and $(5,12)$. The long diagonal of the rhombus is their angle bisector, which we compute as $$\|(5,12)\|(4,3)+\|(4,3)\|(5,12)=(77,99),$$ and can simplify a bit to $(7,9)$. The length of the long diagonal is $12$, so its end point is $${12\over\sqrt{130}}(7,9)=\sqrt{{2\over65}}\left(42,54\right).$$ The missing two sides pass through this point and are parallel to the two known sides. You can find their equations by plugging this point into the left-hand sides of those equations to get the new right-hand sides. E.g., $$3\cdot42\sqrt{{2\over65}}-4\cdot54\sqrt{{2\over65}}=-18\sqrt{{10\over13}}$$ so the equation the side parallel to $3x-4y=0$ is $3x-4y+18\sqrt{{10\over13}}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We can use  parallel vector properties and similitude shrink ratio  $\sigma$ for entire figure of rhombus of 4 lines built around the origin $O$. Let vertices of rhombus be

$$O(9,0),\quad A(3,4),\quad B(5,12),\quad D(3+5=8, 4+12=16);$$

Diagonal length is $\sqrt{8^2+16^2}={8\sqrt5} $ and scale-down ratio  $\sigma= \dfrac{12}{8\sqrt5} =\dfrac{3}{2\sqrt 5} $

Equations of lines $ (OA,OB)$

$$ \dfrac{y-16}{x-8}=\dfrac{12}{5},\quad\dfrac{y-16}{x-8}=\dfrac{4}{3}, $$

and corresponding outer parallel scaled lines $ (DB,DA)$ become

$$ \dfrac{y-16\sigma}{x-8\sigma}=\dfrac{12}{5},\quad\dfrac{y-16\sigma}{x-8\sigma}=\dfrac{4}{3}. $$
which can be further simplified.

Next we find perpendicular bisector of new shortened $OD$ to find points of intersection with old/given line equations of $(OA,OB);$ the slopes do not change but the constant term  $y-$ intercept changes.